# How do I get the content of a custom instance of WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, loop

I've taken a very minimalistic loop, and tried to modify it, so that I can use more then one loop on one page.

The minimalistic loop works fine and gets the content. But my modification to allow it to be re-used fails.

This is the working loop:

```
<?php

if (have_posts()) :
```

?>

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

All good so far. That actually works. But if I want to have more then one loop on a page, I'm forced to work with WP_Query.

So, I modify my loop thus:

```
<?php

$my_query = new WP_Query() ;

if ($my_query->have_posts()) :
```

?>

```
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $my_query->the_content(); ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

But now I get nothing back at all. I don't get any errors, and php after that loop continues to execute. But I'm not getting any content.

Where am I going wrong?
How do I actually get the content?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass some arguments to `new WP_Query` or no database request will be sent. Your check …

```
if ($my_query->have_posts())
```

… will never evaluate to `TRUE`, because there are no data.

Comment: thanks. So now I'm stuck on which parameter to use. I just need the most minimal parameter set possible, in order to just get the actual content of the Page. I've been looking at the docs for WP_Query, but I can't figure this out. Any idea what my args should be?

Comment: @bob The content of the page is in `$GLOBALS['post']`.